# TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported - python, numpy, pandas, folium

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, folium

I am trying to create a Choropleth map using folium, but during the process I encounter the following **error message**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21004/1239111326.py in <module>
----> 1 folium.Choropleth(
      2     geo_data = json,
      3     name = "choropleth",
      4     data = df,
      5     columns = ["state_code", "men"],

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1211         if color_data is not None and key_on is not None:
   1212             real_values = np.array(list(color_data.values()))
-> 1213             real_values = real_values[~np.isnan(real_values)]
   1214             _, bin_edges = np.histogram(real_values, bins=bins)
   1215 

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Here is my code and you could find the table.csv and map.geojson files here - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/206aca1bf6712bfb49e1ce5979da2be220211104093237/204e9a:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

json = f"map.geojson"

map = folium.Map(location = [42.688534, 25.280583], zoom_start = 7)

table = f"table2.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(table, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

folium.Choropleth(
geo_data = json,
name = "choropleth",
data = df,
columns = ["state_code", "men"],
key_on = "feature.properties.state_code",
fill_color = "BuPu",
fill_opacity= 0.7,
line_opacity= 0.2,
legend_name="Men population(n)"
).add_to(map)

map
```

I have found this ([Python / Folium / Choropleth: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170367/python-folium-choropleth-typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported)) similar issue to mine but I still fail to find/apply a solution. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If there is a NaN in the data frame, set it to zero before using it, or delete the row if it is not needed.

Comment: I have already checked for NaN using df.isnull().values.any() but there are no NaN values found in the df.

Comment: I could not refer to the data because it requires membership registration to refer to the data. I may be able to help if I can refer to it.

Comment: I have also uploaded the files to google drive - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_MUWYsTUMu5sa-JRAjHhikSqWav8yDoc?usp=sharing - let me know if this works.

Comment: I am doing a lot of work to resolve the error with information that I can't download the data and load it due to an error in the file. Is it possible to provide the geo JSON file as a URL?

Comment: I managed to find a solution to the error. Had to remove the spacing between the numbers in the table file and it is now working.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I'm sorry I couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to the error. Had to remove the spacing between the numbers in the table file and it is now working.